# Does anyone know how to use the Azure Table Storage - Insert Entity (Preview) Action of Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to do a simple workflow in Logic Apps using the Dynamics 365 for Operations - Get Records (preview) Action and then store the results in the action Azure Table Storage - Insert Entity. By doing a hack I'm able to store the results in JSON in an Azure BLOB. I'm putting @body('Get_records') in the body of Create BLOB, but I want a better solution. The problem is that I do not know how Azure Table Storage - Insert Entity works, I can't find any documentation on it. I would appreciate if someone could guide me in the correct path.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Insert Entity]

Ok, I found the solution. Insert Entity expects this JSON in the entity section: